# Changing the contents of a tag using TinyXML2 C++

Tags: c++, tinyxml2

I want to do this:

1. Load a file.

   Find an element in it with it's attribute value like I want to find the dog tag with colour as brown. `<dog colour="brown">`

   Then I want to change the contents of the tag. For example: from `<dog colour="brown">Baow!</dog>` to `<dog colour="brown">Waow!</dog>`.

All this has to be done using TinyXML2. So far, I could only open the file:

`XMLDocument file;
file.LoadFile("file.xml");`

It would be great if you could help me.

Comment: There is a tutorial here. http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/tutorial0.html

Comment: You want to walk the XML file by selecting an element and iterating children etc. We don’t know the make up of your XML file to give specific advice.

Comment: @Galik The link you provided is for TinyXML 1 and not 2.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so you know how to load the file:

```
XMLDocument file;
file.LoadFile("file.xml");
```

We do not know the syntax of your XML file. But you have to walk down throw the elements.

```
XMLElement *pDog = file.FirstChildElement("dog");
if(pDog != null)
{
    if(pDog->Attribute("colour") == "brown)
    {
        pDog->SetText("Waow!");
    }
}

file.SaveFile("...");
```

As I mentioned, you have to parse the elements through to get to the correct node.

---

The online [readme file](https://github.com/leethomason/tinyxml2/blob/master/readme.md) also states:

> ## Lookup information.
>
> ```
> /* ------ Example 2: Lookup information. ---- */
> {
>   XMLDocument doc;
>   doc.LoadFile( "dream.xml" );
>
>   // Structure of the XML file:
>   // - Element "PLAY"      the root Element, which is the
>   //                       FirstChildElement of the Document
>   // - - Element "TITLE"   child of the root PLAY Element
>   // - - - Text            child of the TITLE Element
>
>   // Navigate to the title, using the convenience function,
>   // with a dangerous lack of error checking.
>   const char* title = doc.FirstChildElement( "PLAY" )->FirstChildElement( "TITLE" )->GetText();
>   printf( "Name of play (1): %s\n", title );
>
>   // Text is just another Node to TinyXML-2. The more
>   // general way to get to the XMLText:
>   XMLText* textNode = doc.FirstChildElement( "PLAY" )->FirstChildElement( "TITLE" )->FirstChild()->ToText();
>   title = textNode->Value();
>   printf( "Name of play (2): %s\n", title );
> }
> ```